# Why has my account on Stack Overflow been removed/deleted?

Tags: support, user-accounts

I have had an account on Stack Overflow for some time. Today I answered a question for the first time:

> [Some of my text all over the website underline automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35775465/some-of-my-text-all-over-the-website-underline-automatically/35775775#35775775)

...and a short while later it appears my account has been removed/deleted and I just cannot understand why.

Please can you provide some insight into this?

Thank you.

Comment: To the close voters: asking on M.SO with an account deleted there and therefore lacking the 5 rep for meta is obviously highly impractical.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

According to our records, while logged into your account, you have clicked the delete link.

If this was not you, I suggest you look around at who else has access to your computer who may have done this.

Comment: I thought there is 24 hours countdown between clicking that button until the account is actually deleted, to let the user regret his/her decision?

Comment: @ShadowWizard That wait doesn't exist if you have zero or one posts, and no votes.

Comment: @animuson thanks, just found [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/151878/152859) - looks like it applies only for deletion activated by moderators, not self deletion.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I do not recall clicking a delete link on purpose. I have just looked in my (new) profile for where this link is, and noticed it's a menu item under Site Settings. I could have accidentally clicked this, not read the JavaScript prompt and idly clicked okay.

Comment: @ShadowWizard The self-serve deletion system still uses that same countdown. Basically, you wait for a delete link to appear in your inbox/email, click it, and it schedules your account for deletion in 24 hours. But users with <2 posts and no votes bypass all of that.

Comment: @animuson thanks, good to know. Is it documented anywhere?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5999/how-can-i-delete-my-account @shadow

Comment: @Shog9 thanks but it does not mention the 24 hours waiting time.